# How to implement input search for dropdown values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

Below is the example I implemented. I want when a user gives input it should match the result and should be selected after typing. Can this implemented with HTML or jQuery or Javascript? Thanks in advance.

```
<select id="funsports" name="funsports">
   <option value="">sports</option>
   <option value="football">grapes</option>
   <option value="tennis">mango</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Your example is just a plain old `select` element. The behaviour you describe sounds like an 'autocomplete' field. There are hundreds of plugins available for this already if you research, [this one](https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/) for example

Comment: Open the dropdown and start typing? This is standard functionality in all modern browsers? Unless you mean you want an actual search field somewhere?

Comment: Maybe try a library like. [chosen](https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/)

Comment: i mean i want to just search like when user type sp... sports should appear

Comment: Yeah i need the same like that @Will

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve what you want, you can use a jquery plugin like [Select2](https://select2.github.io/)

Look at the demos to be sure it has what you're looking for